# ListView onItemClickListener does not work, why?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have got the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.iav.viraprecorder.ServerListFragment"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/recording_details_padding_top_bottom"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/recording_details_padding_top_bottom"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/recording_details_padding_left_right"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/recording_details_padding_left_right">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:id="@+id/server_list_next_button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:enabled="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/list_available_servers"
        android:id="@+id/server_list_heading"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/server_list_hint"
        android:id="@+id/server_list_hint"
        android:layout_below="@+id/server_list_heading"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/server_list_view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/server_list_hint"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/server_list_next_button"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The items of the ListView have got the following style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Type: Anything"
        android:id="@+id/type"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Description: ..."
        android:id="@+id/description"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="API-Level: 2"
        android:id="@+id/api_level"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Generated on: 10.08.2013"
        android:id="@+id/generated_date"
        android:phoneNumber="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Address: 192.168.111.112:32001"
        android:id="@+id/address"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In my ServerListFragment.java I attach an OnItemClickListener to my ListView inside the inViewCreated method. I first get the ListView, set the listener and then add the adapter.

Currently clicks on my list are not received.

Can someone tell me why?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Post the code where you attach that listener

Comment: try OnItemSelectedListener()

Comment: I think it was because of the android:phoneNumber="true", that I inserted accidently. Now everything works fine.

Comment: can you also show your adapter code, please?

Answer (score 0):

Simply set

```
android:focusable ="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode ="false"
```

for your all `UI` views in custom view which is inflating in `getView()` method.